# Issue with Special Characters in Appending Data to a Sheet with Flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, zoho

I am working on an application that integrates with the Zoho API to append data to a Zoho Sheet. I am facing an issue when trying to pass special characters in the CSV data of my API request.

I have a Flutter application where users input various fields, and these fields are then used to construct the CSV data that I need to send to the Zoho API. The issue arises when a field contains special characters such as double quotes (") or hyphens (-).

```
Future<void> addRecord() async {
    const String worksheetName =
        'RMA'; // Replace with the actual name of your worksheet

// Check if any field is empty
    if (selectedBrand == null ||
        selectedProduct == null ||
        sku.isEmpty ||
        serialNumber.isEmpty ||
        orderNumber.isEmpty ||
        damageType.isEmpty ||
        comments.isEmpty) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Alert'),
            content: const Text('Please fill in all fields.'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
      return;
    }

// Prepare the CSV data to be appended using the field values
    final String csvData =
        '$selectedBrand,$selectedProduct,$sku,$serialNumber,$dateOfInput,$customerPurchaseDate,$orderNumber,$damageType,$comments';

    // Encode the CSV data before using it in the URL
    final String encodedCsvData = Uri.encodeComponent(csvData);

    final ZohoApi zohoApi = ZohoApi();
    final String? accessToken = await zohoApi.getAccessToken();
    const String resourceId = TEST
        ''; // Replace with your actual resource ID
    const String corsProxyUrl = 'https://corsproxy.io/?';

    if (accessToken != null) {
      final Uri url = Uri.parse(
          '${corsProxyUrl}https://sheet.zoho.com/api/v2/$resourceId?method=worksheet.csvdata.append&worksheet_name=$worksheetName&data=$encodedCsvData');

      try {
        final response = await http.post(
          url,
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Zoho-oauthtoken $accessToken',
          },
        );

        // Handle the response based on the status code
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          // Successful response
          print('Data appended successfully!');

          // Show success dialog
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Alert'),
                content: const Text('Data appended successfully!'),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text('OK'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
          setState(() {
            // Clear the fields
            selectedBrand = null;
            selectedProduct = null;
            sku = '';
            serialNumber = '';
            orderNumber = '';
            damageType = '';
            comments = '';
            _brandSearchController.clear();
            _productSearchController.clear();
            _purchaseDateController.clear();
            _commentsController.clear();
            _damageTypeController.clear();
            _orderNumberController.clear();
            _SerialNumberController.clear();
            _SkuNumberController.clear();
          });
        } else {
          // Handle error response
          print('Error3: ${response.statusCode} - ${response.body}');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // Handle network or other request errors
        print('Error4: $e');
      }
    } else {
      // Handle access token retrieval failure scenario
      print('Failed to obtain access token.');
    }
  }
```

When the CSV data contains special characters, the API request fails. However, if I use plain text without special characters, the request works as expected.

For example, if I use the following product name:

> Elgato Cam Link 4K

It works perfectly fine. But if I use a product name like:

> Devo Gaming monitor - DFI24165 - 24" IPS FHD 165Hz 0.5ms

The request fails.

I've ensured that I'm using `Uri.encodeComponent` to properly encode the CSV data before sending it in the URL. Is there something else I need to consider or do differently when dealing with special characters in API requests? Could this be an issue with the Zoho API handling special characters?